# Android and Eclipse errors

Tags: java, android, eclipse, compiler-errors

I am new to android.
I created new Android app project. Min SDK: 16, target: 21. And I got bunch of errors similar to this one:

```
[2016-05-31 22:36:16 - project1] E:\workspace\project1\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2016-05-31 22:36:16 - project1]
```

and also red underlined lines: "The import android.support.v7" cannot be resolved. The same with ActionBarUtilty and many others.
It was new project!

I reinstalled SDK and eclipse...it didn't helped.
I can't find solution..I tried to include .jar libraries from SDK but I am doing it wrong or it doesn't help..

Comment: Did you download the appropriate libraries? And also, wouldn't it be easier to use an IDE which is made for android, Android Studio?

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse is dead for Android development, I think since 2013-2014. Download Android Studio https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html , You will see it very simple to start a new project.
You can download the sdk and android-studio in one installation.